# Problem With 3D Contour Plot

Tags: plotting

So I am very new to Mathematica and I'm using version 9. I need to plot a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ is equal to $y^2$ when $x > y$ and equal to $10 \sin(x)$ when $x < y$. I want two contour plots, one in 2D and one in 3D. So far, I have plotted the 2D version without a problem in the following way:

```
f3[x_, y_, z_] := If[x > y, y^2, If[x < y, 10*Sin[x]]];
ContourPlot[f3[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: 2D Plot]

Attempting to plot the 3D version, I tried entering this:

```
ContourPlot3D[f3[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 20}]
```

and sadly received this monstrosity:

[image: 3D Plot]

Any idea why? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, I'm hoping it's a simple fix considering I've only been using the software for a few days.

EDIT: In response to some of the comments, this is the example that was provided (e.g. what it's supposed to look like):

[image: 3D Plot 2]

I understand that my function depends only on x and y, I only added the z to make the plot work. To clarify my question, how do I make it look like the second plot?
Thanks for the help so far by the way

Comment: What's wrong with that result?  What were you expecting?

Comment: sure you don't just want `Plot3D` ? Your function isn't a function of z at all..

Comment: If you give the option `contours->50` to `ContourPlot3D` it should be more apparent what you are plotting..(slow)

Comment: To put wxffles' comment another way, the plot looks correct.  Also, your words say $f(x,y)$, but your code defines $f(x,y,z)$.  Probably you want `f[x_, y_]:=...` and `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x,...}, {y,...}]` and so forth.

Comment: just edited to contain more info. accidentally copied all the graphs but its the 2nd row, 2nd column

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question, this is what you are looking for:

```
f3[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{y^2, x > y}, {10 Sin[x], x <= y}}]

Plot3D[f3[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

These are the changes I made:

- $f(x,y)$ is a two-variable function (i.e. $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), so define it as such.  Do not use `z` in the argument list.
- `ContourPlot3D` is for plotting implicit surfaces defined by $f(x,y,z) = 0$.  If I understand you correctly, you just wanted to plot $f(x,y)$ with contour lines corresponding to the values of $f$.  So use `Plot3D` for plotting and set the [`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshFunctions.html) option to `#3 &` to have the contour lines.  `#3` means "third argument" which for `Plot3D`'d mesh function is the height, i.e. the value of $f$.  The meaning of mesh function arguments are different for each plotting function and you'll find them in the documentation.
- Finally, I replaced `If` by `Piecewise`.  The benefit is that Mathematica will be able to recognize the break at the line $x=y$ and make sure that the cut between the two regions is smooth.  See [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html) for details.  Generally, use `If` as a programming construct and use `Piecewise` to define mathematical functions meant for symbolic operations.
- Optionally you might add `MaxRecursion -> 4` for much smoother contour lines (see [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxRecursion.html)).

Comment: Yes!! This is what I was trying to do. Thank you so much!! Sorry if it was unclear.